# Asp.net core Identity and Token Based Authetication

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identity

I have following scenario. I write asp.net core web api which will be used by mobile and web (asp.net core mvc web app) apps.

I authenticate user using asp.net core identity framework class SignInManager (add account controller and related classes manually) and then generate oauth token which will be used by client applications. By doing so I have 2 identities associated with the user. one is created by after I login using SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync and second is created by generating oauth JWT token.

Is this correct approach or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/27/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/

that might shed some light on what direction to go. there is also another blog post about using IdentityServer4 (3rd party) works well.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/01/23/asp-net-core-authentication-with-identityserver4/

Comment: I did used identity server 4 and it slow down my application.

Comment: It is working but every time request go through identity server pipeline before hit repository services, it slow down the overall performance. My request to any authorize controller, first redirect to identity server endpoint and then back to my controller.

Comment: how long ago was that?

Comment: Last month, I put this on forum but no help found. Is it true that every request first go to identity server service every time after login then back to our services?

Comment: If you authenticating with a login from a mobile app, then yes since the token expires after a period of time determined by you with setup.  As for time it takes for server to respond I am not sure why it affected you so bad in this instance but I setup based on that link and it was flawless.